# You can't specify target table 's1' for update in FROM clause

Tags: sql, sql-update

```
UPDATE sch_scores s1 
   SET s1.Score = '4' 
WHERE EXISTS (select * 
              from sch_scores s2 
              WHERE s2.ResultID = "24614" 
                AND s2.FormatID = "9" 
                AND s2.Score = "4")
```

> You can't specify target table 's1' for update in FROM clause

I get that error when the above query. pls what could be the prob?

Comment: i use mysql for that

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE sch_scores 
SET Score = '4' 
WHERE EXISTS (select * 
              from sch_scores s2 
              WHERE s2.ResultID = "24614" 
                AND s2.FormatID = "9" 
                AND s2.Score = "4")
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to specify an instance in the update clause ( remove s1 )

```
UPDATE sch_scores
    SET Score = '4' 
    WHERE EXISTS (select * from sch_scores s2 WHERE s2.ResultID = "24614" AND s2.FormatID = "9" AND s2.Score = "4")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant and dont need to provide alias "s1" in update query. It is pretty un necessary to give temporary name to table while updating isnt it?

```
 UPDATE sch_scores
   SET Score = '4' 
WHERE EXISTS (select * 
              from sch_scores s2 
              WHERE s2.ResultID = "24614" 
                AND s2.FormatID = "9" 
                AND s2.Score = "4")
```

Comment: I still get same error even after removing the alias
UPDATE sch_scores SET Score = '4' WHERE ( SELECT * FROM `sch_scores` WHERE sch_scores.ResultID = "24614" AND sch_scores.FormatID = "9" AND sch_scores.Score = "4")